# AWS QuickSight programmatic access

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I have been recently involved in a project where I have to leverage the QuickSight APIs and update a dashboard programmatically. I can perform all the other actions but I am unable to update the dashboard from a template. I have tried a couple of different ideas, but all in vain.
Is there anyone who has already worked with the **UpdateDashboard** API or point me to some detailed documentation where I can understand if I am actually missing anything?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the **AWS QuickSight Java V2 API**. TO make this work, you need to follow the quick start instructions here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/getting-started.html

You need to get these values:

- account - your account number
- dashboardId - the dashboard id value
- dataSetArn -- the data set ID value
- analysisArn - the analysis Arn value

Once you go through the above topics - you will have all of these resource and ready to call **UpdateDashboard** . Here is the Java example that updates a Dashboard.

```
package com.example.quicksight;

import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.quicksight.QuickSightClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.quicksight.model.*;

/*
    Before running this code example, follow the Getting Started with Data Analysis in Amazon QuickSight located here:

    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/getting-started.html

    This code example uses resources that you created by following that topic such as the DataSet Arn value.

 */

public class UpdateDashboard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage: UpdateDashboard <account> <dashboardId> <>\n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "  account - the account to use.\n\n" +
                "  dashboardId - the dashboard id value to use.\n\n" +
                "  dataSetArn - the ARN of the dataset.\n\n" +
                "  analysisArn - the ARN of an existing analysis";


        String account = "<account id>";
        String dashboardId = "<dashboardId>";
        String dataSetArn = "<dataSetArn>";
        String analysisArn = "<Analysis Arn>";
        QuickSightClient qsClient = QuickSightClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        try {

            DataSetReference dataSetReference = DataSetReference.builder()
                    .dataSetArn(dataSetArn)
                    .dataSetPlaceholder("Dataset placeholder2")
                    .build();

            // Get a template ARN to use.
            String arn = getTemplateARN(qsClient, account, dataSetArn, analysisArn);
            DashboardSourceTemplate sourceTemplate = DashboardSourceTemplate.builder()
                    .dataSetReferences(dataSetReference)
                   .arn(arn)
                    .build();

            DashboardSourceEntity sourceEntity = DashboardSourceEntity.builder()
                    .sourceTemplate(sourceTemplate)
                    .build();


            UpdateDashboardRequest dashboardRequest = UpdateDashboardRequest.builder()
                    .awsAccountId(account)
                    .dashboardId(dashboardId)
                    .name("UpdateTest")
                     .sourceEntity(sourceEntity)
                    .themeArn("arn:aws:quicksight::aws:theme/SEASIDE")
                    .build();

            UpdateDashboardResponse response = qsClient.updateDashboard(dashboardRequest);
            System.out.println("Dashboard " + response.dashboardId() + " has been updated");

        } catch (QuickSightException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static String getTemplateARN(QuickSightClient qsClient, String account, String dataset, String analysisArn) {

        String arn = "";
        try {
            DataSetReference setReference = DataSetReference.builder()
                    .dataSetArn(dataset)
                    .dataSetPlaceholder("Dataset placeholder2")
                    .build();

            TemplateSourceAnalysis templateSourceAnalysis = TemplateSourceAnalysis.builder()
                    .dataSetReferences(setReference)
                    .arn(analysisArn)
                    .build();

            TemplateSourceEntity sourceEntity = TemplateSourceEntity.builder()
                    .sourceAnalysis(templateSourceAnalysis)
                    .build();

            CreateTemplateRequest createTemplateRequest = CreateTemplateRequest.builder()
                    .awsAccountId(account)
                    .name("NewTemplate")
                    .sourceEntity(sourceEntity)
                    .templateId("a9a277fb-7239-4890-bc7a-8a3e82d67a37") // Specify a GUID value
                    .build();

            CreateTemplateResponse response = qsClient.createTemplate(createTemplateRequest);
            arn = response.arn();

        } catch (QuickSightException e) {
            System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return arn;
    }
}
```